# How do you order by a complex expression in python SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to sort the results of a list of posts by a "hotness" algorithm. Basically I want something like:

```
Posts.query.order_by(Post.votes + 1000/(datetime.utcnow() - Post.datetime)).all()
```

However, this kind of code does not work as expected. It doesn't take the time into account at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
(
    db.session.query(Post)
    .order_by(
        Post.votes + 1000 / (db.extract('epoch', datetime.now() - Post.datetime))
    )
)
```

Problem with your approach is that sqlalchemy is not able to decide how to divide an Integral value and a difference in time. So you have to manually interpret the difference in time as an integral value. Here I extract the epoch from the difference, you could choose to extract what ever.